# How to deal with pipe as data in pipe delimited file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file

I am trying to solve a problem where my csv data looks like below:

```
A|B|C 
"Jon"|"PR | RP"|"MN"
"Pam | Map"|"Ecom"|"unity"
"What"|"is"this" happening"|"?"
```

That is, it is pipe delimited and has quotes as text qualifier but it also has pipe and quotes with in the data values. I have already tried

**Update based on the comments**

I tried to select `|` as delimiter and `"` as Text Qualifier but when trying to import data to OLEDB Destination i receive the following error:

> couldn't find column delimiter for column B

Comment: If you have both quotes and pipes in your data, it's time to change both your delimiter and your text identifier (or at least your text identifier).

Comment: this is not valid CSV file.

Comment: What happen if you select `"` as text qualifier and `|` as column delimiter?

Comment: The proper escape for the last row is `"What"|"is ""this"" happening"|"?"`

Comment: Hadi, When i do that although in the flat file connection manager, it is able to preview the columns as I want but when I export it the OLE DB destination, it says couldn't find column delimiter for column B.

Comment: Larnu, I don't know how to do it. Is there a way I can do it in SSIS?

Comment: You could use a script component that uses a regex to fix this row:  "What"|"is"this" happening"|"?". It looks like you need to do a regex.replace on the " and replace with '.

Comment: @Yogita is the issue solved? did you tried the suggestion given by other users. if so then you should accept an answer or write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the `Column Delimiter` property to `|` (vertical bar) and the `Text Qualifier` property to `"` within the `Flat File Connection Manager`

[image]

[image]

If these is still not working then you have some bad rows in the Flat File Source which you must handle using the Error Output:

- [Flat File source Error Output connection in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582390/flat-file-source-error-output-connection-in-ssis)
- [SQL SERVER – SSIS Component Error Outputs](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/26/sql-server-ssis-component-error-outputs-notes-from-the-field-034/)

Comment: Hadi, This is what I have been doing but the problem is it fails when you connect it to an OLE DB destination

Comment: @Yogita I think there is a bad rows, you should use the error output from the Flat File Source to retrieve these rows

Comment: @yogita check the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582390/flat-file-source-error-output-connection-in-ssis

Comment: @yogita the only way to achieve this is as mentioned, set the delimiters and use the Error Output options.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the delimiters and using error output didn't quite work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up writing a c sharp script to remove the initial and last quote and set the column delimiter to quote pipe quote ("|") in SSIS. Code was as below:

```
public void Main()
    {
        String folderSource = "path";
        String folderTarget = "path";

        foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderSource))
        {
            String targetfilepath = folderTarget + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
            System.IO.File.Delete(targetfilepath);
            int icount = 1;
            foreach (String row in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file))
            {
                if (icount == 1)
                {
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(targetfilepath, row.Replace("|", "\"|\""));

                }
                else
                {

                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(targetfilepath, row.Substring(1, row.Length - 2));
                }
                icount = icount + 1;
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(targetfilepath, Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```