# SSIS flat file with values containing text qualifier

Tags: csv, ssis, etl, flat-file, delimited

I received a flat file that cannot be generated in other way. The delimited is a comma and the text qualifier is a double quote. The problem is that sometimes a have a double quote in the value. In example:

```
"0","12345", "Centre d"edu et de recherche", "B8E7"
```

Because of the double quote in the value, I received this error:

> [Flat File Source [58]] Error: The column delimiter for column "XYZ" was not found.
>
> [Flat File Source [58]] Error: An error occurred while processing file "C:\somefile.csv" on data row 296.

What can I do to process this file?

I use SSIS 2016 with Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Are you sure that Centre d"edu has one quote, not two next to each other? If there is only one, I would ask whoever is generating file for you to fix it. If not fixed, you can't correctly recognize embalmed  string like ","

Comment: Yes I'm sure, but we don't have control on the way the file is generated. I must find a way to deal with it.

Comment: I don't know your situation, but my answer would be that this file can't be imported in a maintainable way and escalate to whoever creating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Flat File Source error output to redirect bad rows to another flat file and correct values manually while all valid rows will be processed.

There are many links online to learn more about Flat File Source Error Output:

- [Flat File source Error Output connection in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582390/flat-file-source-error-output-connection-in-ssis)
- [How to Avoid Package Design Flaws When Sourcing Data From Flat Files](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-avoid-package-design-flaws-when-sourcing-data-from-flat-files/)
- [Flat File Source Editor (Error Output Page)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/flat-file-source-editor-error-output-page?view=sql-server-2014)

---

### Update 1 - Workaround using Script Component and conditional split

Since Flat File error output is not working you can use a script component with a conditional split to filter bad rows, the following update is a step by step guide to implement that:

1. Add a Flat File connection manager, Go To advanced Tab, Delete all columns except one column and change it length to 4000

[image]

2. Add a script component, Go to Input and Output Column Tab, add desired output columns (in this example 4 columns) and add a Flag Column of type `DT_BOOL`
3. Inside the Script Component write the following script to check if the number of columns is 4 then `Flag` = `True` which means this is a valid row else set `Flag` as `False` which mean that this is a bad row:

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {

        if (!Row.Column0_IsNull && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Row.Column0))
        {

            string[] cells = Row.Column0.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);


            if (cells.Length == 4)
            {

                Row.Col1 = cells[0].TrimStart('\"');
                Row.Col2 = cells[1];
                Row.Col3 = cells[2];
                Row.Col4 = cells[3].TrimEnd('\"');
                Row.Flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bool cancel;
                Row.Flag = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            Row.Col1_IsNull = true;
            Row.Col2_IsNull = true;
            Row.Col3_IsNull = true;
            Row.Col4_IsNull = true;
            Row.Flag = true;
        }

    }

}
```

4. Add a conditional split to split rows based on `Flag` column

[image]

5. Map the Valid Rows output to the OLEDB Destination, and the Bad Rows output to another flat file where you only map `Column0`

[image]

Comment: I tried but it doesn't redirect. Maybe It's because it can't guess which column is which.

Comment: @Bradford1138 i will provide a step by step workaround in a while

Comment: This would work, except I need all the row. I'm migrating SSIS 2008 to 2016 and in 2008, the file worked. So I need the same data in 2016. This guy explains the same problem as mine:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/12/29/flat-file-connection-manager-doesnt-work-for-rows-containing-embedded-qualifiers/

Comment: @Bradford1138 what do you mean by `i need all the row`? Did you try the solution?

Comment: @Bradford1138 in addition this solution will work on embedded qualifiers also since the line is splited by delimiter located within two qualifiers

Comment: I didn't understand correctly. It's working now. Thank you